# Operators acting on the space of solutions of a system of ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, representation-theory, hypergeometric-function

A system of the hypergeometric equation (HGE), associated with a set $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ of parameters is defined/obtained in the following way. Let $\Psi$ be a solution of the hypergeometric equation
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-eq} z (1 - z) \frac{d^{2} \Psi}{dz^{2}} + (\gamma - (\alpha + \beta + 1)z) \frac{d \Psi}{dz} - \alpha \beta \Psi,
\end{eqnarray}
consider a $2$-dimensional vector space with a chosen basis set and introduce
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-LP} \bar{\psi} (z) = \Psi (z) \bar{{e}}_{1} + \dot{\Psi} (z) \bar{{e}}_{2}, \;\;\; {\rm with} \;\;\; \dot{\Psi} (z) = z \frac{d \Psi(z)}{dz}
\end{eqnarray}
being the logarithmic derivative of $\Psi$. We then derive
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-LP-2} \frac{d \bar{\psi}}{dz} = \frac{d \Psi}{dz} \bar{{e}}_{1} + \frac{d}{dz} \left(z \frac{d \Psi}{dz}\right) \bar{{e}}_{2} = \frac{1}{z} (\dot{\Psi} \bar{{e}}_{1} + (1 - \gamma) \dot{\Psi} \bar{{e}}_{2}) - \frac{1}{z - 1} ((\alpha + \beta + 1 - \gamma) \dot{\Psi} \bar{{e}}_{2}) + \alpha \beta \Psi \bar{e}_{2}),
\end{eqnarray}
resulting in the following system:
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-LP-3} && \frac{d \bar{\psi}}{dz} = \frac{\bar{A}}{z} \bar{\psi} + \frac{\bar{B}}{z-1} \bar{\psi}, \;\;\; a = 1 - \gamma, \;\;\; s = \alpha + \beta, \;\;\; p = \alpha \beta, \nonumber \\
&& \bar{A}_{11} = 0, \;\;\; \bar{A}_{12} = 1, \;\;\; \bar{B}_{11} = 0, \;\;\; \bar{B}_{12} = 0, \nonumber \\
&& \bar{A}_{21} = 0, \;\;\; \bar{A}_{22} = a, \;\;\; \bar{B}_{21} = -p, \;\;\; \bar{B}_{22} = - (s + a).
\end{eqnarray}

Now of course it is known that two linearly independent solutions of the HGE are:
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-LP-4} \Psi_{1} = F (\alpha, \beta, \gamma; z), \;\;\; \Psi_{2} = z^{1 - \gamma} F (\beta - \gamma + 1, \alpha - \gamma + 1; 2 - \gamma; z),
\end{eqnarray}
so one can easily check that the following are two linearly independent solutions to the system:
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-LP-5} \bar{\psi}_{1} = \Psi_{1} \bar{{e}}_{1} + \dot{\Psi}_{1} \bar{{e}}_{2}, \;\;\; \bar{\psi}_{2} = \Psi_{2} \bar{{e}}_{1} + \dot{\Psi}_{2} \bar{{e}}_{2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Now, consider the following change of basis:
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-LP-7} && {e}_{1} = \bar{{e}}_{1}, \;\;\; {e}_{2} = \bar{{e}}_{1} + a \bar{{e}}_{2}, \nonumber \\
&& \bar{{e}}_{1} = {e}_{1}, \;\;\; \bar{{e}}_{2} = - a^{-1} {e}_{1} + a^{-1} {e}_{2}.
\end{eqnarray}

Acting with $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ on the new basis set $({e}_{1}, {e}_{2})$ we obtain the system written in the new basis,
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{HG-LP-8} && \frac{d \psi}{dz} = \frac{A}{z} \psi + \frac{B}{z-1} \psi, \nonumber \\
&& A_{11} = 0, \;\;\; A_{12} = 0, \;\;\; B_{11} = p a^{-1}, \;\;\;  B_{12} = p a^{-1} + (s + a), \nonumber \\
&& A_{21} = 0, \;\;\; \bar{A}_{22} = a, \;\;\; B_{21} = -p a^{-1}, \;\;\; B_{22} = - p a^{-1} - (s + a), \nonumber \\
&& {\psi}_{1} = (\Psi_{1} - a^{-1} \dot{\Psi}_{1}) {e}_{1} + a^{-1} \dot{\Psi}_{1} {e}_{2}, \;\;\; {\psi}_{2} = (\Psi_{2} - a^{-1} \dot{\Psi}_{2}) {e}_{1} + a^{-1} \dot{\Psi}_{2} {e}_{2},
\end{eqnarray}

If we take $M^{0}$ to be an operator in the space of solutions of the HGE, particularly, the monodromy based at a point $z_{0}$ near $0$ that loops around the singularity at $1$, then we can think of $M^{0}_{1}$ (the monodromy based at a point $z_{0}$ near $0$ that loops around the singularity at $1$ for the first system described above) as a 2x2 matrix that is equal to $M^{0}$. Now the claim is that the change of basis from the first system to the second system does not affect the monodromy, i.e. $M^{0}_{2}$ = $M^{0}$, but I am not sure how to show this.

The only thing I could think of was the following:

$$
\begin{align}
M^{0}\psi_{1}
&=(M^{0}\Psi_{1} - a^{-1}M^{0}\dot{\Psi_{1}})e_{1} + a^{-1}M^{0}\dot{\Psi_{1}}e_{2}\\
&= [m^{0}_{11}\Psi_{1} + m^{0}_{21}\Psi_{2} - a^{-1}(m^{0}_{11}\dot{\Psi_{1}} + m^{0}_{21}\dot{\Psi_{2}})]e_{1} + a^{-1}(m^{0}_{11}\dot{\Psi_{1}} + m^{0}_{21}\dot{\Psi_{2}})e_{2}\\
&= m^{0}_{11}[(\Psi_{1} - a^{-1}\dot{\Psi_{1}})e_{1} + a^{-1}\dot{\Psi_{1}}e_{2}] + m^{0}_{21}[(\Psi_{2} - a^{-1}\dot{\Psi_{2}})e_{1} + a^{-1}\dot{\Psi_{2}}e_{2}]\\
&= m^{0}_{11}\psi_{1} + m^{0}_{21}\psi_{2}
\end{align}
$$
and similarly acting with $M^{0}$ on $\psi_{2}$ we get $M^{0}\psi_{2} = m^{0}_{12}\psi_{1} + m^{0}_{22}\psi_{2}$.

Meaning that $M^{0}$ written in the basis set $\{ \psi_{1}, \psi_{2} \}$ does not change.

Is this correct?